# Why didn't guava ripen after being stored in the fridge?

Tags: fruit, ripe

I'm fairly new to guava, and was thinking it was strange that the color of the guava didn't change after leaving them out for a week so I could eat the other pack. The guava turned brown on the outside, but didn't yellow at all.

Why did this happen?

How should I keep guava if one pack is being eaten, while the other pack is being kept to eat after?

Comment: How did you keep the ones that didn't ripen? Warm, cold, paper bag… etc? Climacteric fruits need ethylene to ripen, hence the paper bag. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ripening

Comment: they were kept in the packaging they came in

Comment: What was the packaging they came in? Airtight plastic film? Clamshell plastic with air holes? A cardboard box? When my grocer has guava, they don't come in and packaging

Comment: it was a clear plastic fruit container for 9 pieces of fruit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [epicurious](https://www.epicurious.com/ingredients/how-to-eat-guava-in-smoothies-salads-desserts-article) *(I love their [YouTube channel](https://www.youtube.com/user/epicuriousdotcom))*:

> You can buy hard, green guavas and allow them to ripen at room temperature. Placing them in a paper bag with a banana or apple will allow them to ripen faster. Guavas may be treated with edible wax to delay the ripening process, so you may want to rinse them off to speed ripening.